# Как перебрать файлы из папки в другую папку?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Хочу взять файлы из одной папки и после перебора закинуть в другую, отобранные. Пока не очень выходит. Берем файл из одной папки, вычисляем квантиль по столбцу - некое среднее значение и если квантиль а больше значения b - сохраняем в файл. И так все перебираем из папки и сохраняем в новую папку.

```
from pandas import read_csv 
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv('C:\Python\JAMN.csv')
df['vol'] = df['Close'] * df['Volume']

a = df['vol'].quantile([0.10, 0.20, 0.40, 0.60, 0.80, 0.95, 0.99, 1], interpolation='nearest') # квантиль
b = 400000 # объем который нужен чтобы сохранить файл

# здесь как то должно быть, что если квантиль 0.20 больше значения b, то сохраняем файл

df.to_csv('С:/JAMN.csv')
```

Пример [файлов](https://dropmefiles.com/KBp5I).

Comment: `если квантиль 0.20 больше значения b, то сохраняем файл` - совсем непонятно что вы пытаетесь сделать. 20% квантиль - это одно скалярное число посчитанное для всех строк фрейма, которое вы сравниваете со скаляром `b`. __Что и куда вы хотите сохранить__ если результат сравнения этих двух скаляров - истина?

Comment: т.е. если перефразировать - вы хотите оставить только те исходные CSV файлы, которые удовлетворяют условию и скопировать их без изменений в другую папку? А те которые не удовлетворяют - не копировать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from pathlib import Path
import shutil

p = Path(r"/path/to/csv_files")
res_dir = Path(r"/path/to/result")
b = 400000 # объем который нужен чтобы сохранить файл
quant = 0.2

for f in p.glob("*.csv"):
    df = pd.read_csv(f).eval("vol = Close * Volume")
    if df["vol"].quantile(quant, interpolation='nearest') > b:
        shutil.copy(str(f), res_dir / f.name)
```

PS данный код не тестировался, соответственно он может содержать опечатки / ошибки